# Add Text After Price in Spesific Theme Phtml

Tags: price, phtml

I can only add  text before price. I use MeigeeTeam's Bizarre theme. Here is the code including my edit in price.phtml

```
?php else: ?>
        <span class="fiyat"><?php echo $this->__("Adet Fiyatı") ?></span>
            <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
                <?php if ($_finalPrice == $_price): ?>
                    <?php echo str_replace('class="price"', 'class="price" itemprop="price"', $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, true)); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php echo str_replace('class="price"', 'class="price" itemprop="price"', $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPrice, true)); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
```

This piece of code is starts at line 208 in

> app/design/frontend/bizarre/default/template/catalog/product

Answer (score 0):

Well it's my mistake to can't be able to think a shortcut. Considering this, you guys can humiliate me all the ways dat you want :)

I've addded text after price just editing currency symbol under Magento Configuration and I just typed my text :)

When I searched at the Google nobody found that silly solution before and I don't know why :) Ahah.